# Type undefined reference to 'OSD0_WRITE'

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, compilation

I am compiling a C program with gcc 4.8.2 compiler in Eclipse Luna running on Ubuntu.

I got an error that says:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
undefined reference to'OSD0_WRITE'  main.c  /stm32107/src   line 120 C/C++ Problem
```

**main.c**

```
#include "OSD.H"

void OSD0_WRITE (   
uint8_t *YAZI,              uint8_t  FONT_PROPERTIES, 
uint16_t X_COORDINATE,      uint16_t Y_COORDINATE, 
uint8_t  FONT_RANGE_X,      uint8_t  FONT_RANGE_Y,
uint8_t  FONT_SIZE_X,       uint8_t  FONT_SIZE_Y, 
uint8_t  CHARACTER_DIM_X,   uint8_t  CHARACTER_DIM_Y,
uint8_t  FONT_BLINK,        uint8_t  FONT_FADE             );

int main(void)
{
uint8_t TEXT[] = "123456789012345678901234567890";

OSD0_WRITE(TEXT ,0x05,45,45,1,1,30,5,1,1,2,15);
} /* main.c */
```

**OSD.C**

```
#include "OSD.H"
void OSD0_WRITE (   
uint8_t *YAZI,              uint8_t  FONT_PROPERTIES, 
uint16_t X_COORDINATE,      uint16_t Y_COORDINATE, 
uint8_t  FONT_RANGE_X,      uint8_t  FONT_RANGE_Y,
uint8_t  FONT_SIZE_X,       uint8_t  FONT_SIZE_Y, 
uint8_t  CHARACTER_DIM_X,   uint8_t  CHARACTER_DIM_Y,
uint8_t  FONT_BLINK,        uint8_t  FONT_FADE             )
{

    TxBurst(0x400,FONT_SIZE_X, TEXT);

    OSD0_XY(X_COORDINATE,Y_COORDINATE);
.....
.....
....



} /* OSD0_WRITE */
```

*****  build log *************
Compiling for STM32F107 Cortex M3 device. Here of build log details.

[image]

Comment: is the actual file name capitalized like OSD.C ? Can you rename this to at least have a lower case file extension, OSD.c and try again, since gcc compiles a .C file as C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is the actual file name capitalized like OSD.C ? Can you rename this to at least have a lower case file extension, OSD.c and try again, since gcc compiles a .C file as C++. –  Answered @nos

Answer (score 0):

OSD.o isn't linked to the solution, you should add OSD.C to the list of source files in the makefile